# sqltextinfo gets truncated while copying to excel

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I need to get a column 'sqltextinfo' from log table but the text is not correctly placed in a cell when I copy it to excel.

I tried the following query to get this. But it throws error -9134 result exceeded maximum length

oreplace(oreplace(otranslate(sqltextinfo),', ',''),chr(10),chr(13),'') sqltextinfo

is there any way to use the above query without using substr

Please help

Comment: I think your parentheses are in the wrong place, but that may be just a typo. Also you seem to have switched usage of OREPLACE (string) and OTRANSLATE (individual characters). But neither of those relates specifically to the 9134 error from OREPLACE: The result is limited to 16000 bytes when the input to OREPLACE is VARCHAR. You could CAST the argument to CLOB and CAST the result back to VARCHAR as a workaround. (I don't think OTRANSLATE accepts/returns CLOB.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to replace any whitespace with a single `' '`:

```
Cast( RegExp_Replace(Cast(SqlTextInfo AS CLOB(31000)), '\s+', ' ',1,0,'c') AS VARCHAR(31000))
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. the query works as expected. but the text is still truncated in few rows as it is very long. is there anything I could do to get full text?

Comment: You will get multiple rows in QryLogSQLV in 31k junks for large queries, which must be ordered by SqlRowNo. There are ways to combine them into a single CLOB, but then you'll hit Excel's limit of 32767 characters in a single cell :-)

Comment: Got it :-) Thanks for ur quick response.. Could you please explain the arguments given in the above query?

Comment: In fact, you don't need the arguments, they are a leftover from a cut&paste.  `\s` indicates the whitespace (CR, LF, Tab, etc.). 1 is the *position* where the search starts, 0 the *occurence* of the pattern to replace (0 means *all* and is the default anyway) and the *match argument* c means *case sensitive* , which obviously doesn't matter for white space